# Laravel 5.2 custom package route not found

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I created a custom package following the documentation. (https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/packages#routing)

I added a route in the custom routes file, it appears when checking with "php artisan route:list" but I get NotFoundHttpException.

I used "php artisan route:clear" to clear the routes cache but the issue persists.

If I add the route in the main app routes files works fine.

**Service provider:**

```
/**
 * Bootstrap the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__ . '/../database/migrations/' => database_path('migrations')
    ], 'migrations');

    if (! $this->app->routesAreCached()) {
        require __DIR__.'/../Http/routes.php';
    }
}
```

**Custom routes file:**

```
Route::get('foo', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find solution ?

Answer (score 1):

For the informatie you give here i cannot just give a clear answer.

If your package structure is like this

```
PackageMainDir
  - src
    - Controllers
    - Migrations
    - Models
    PackageServiceProvider.php
    Routes.php
  - test
  - vendor
  composer.json
  phpunit.xml
```

You will have in your PackageServiceProvider.php the following code:

```
/**
 * Bootstrap the application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->publishes([
        realpath(__DIR__.'/Migrations') => $this->getDatabasePath().'/migrations',
    ]);

    if (! $this->app->routesAreCached()) {
        require_once(__DIR__ . '/Routes.php');
    }
}
```

I hope its not to late and otherwise other user will have the profit of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I don't know why but after trying `php artisan config:cache`, changes in config/app.php were considered, and the custom service provider loaded the boot( ) method.

Answer (score 0):

I also same experience for that after some research and solved it! please edit your code in the package service provider file `function boot()`.

```
public function boot()
    {

        if (! $this->app->routesAreCached()) {
            require __DIR__ . '/Routes.php';
        }
    }
```

After this run the `php artisan config:cache` code in cmd i solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved it this way

```
public function boot()
{
    $path = realpath(__DIR__.'/../');

    $this->loadRoutesFrom($path.'/Routes/web.php');
    $this->loadViewsFrom($path.'/Resources/views/Formato','formato');
}

public function register()
{

}
```

I hope this can be useful